# Rails ordering through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to sort from model `Members` ascending from `Member.board.order`

On my controller, `institutional_controller.rb` I have:

```
@display = Member.includes(:board).where('is_board = ?', true).order('member.board.order ASC').references(:board)

# board.rb and member.rb

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :board
end


# index.html.erb

<% @display.each do |member|  %> [...]
```

And the error that I am getting is:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "board"
LINE 1: ...= "members"."id" WHERE (is_board = 't')  ORDER BY member.board [...]
```

Thank you. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do run your query on the console and add `.explain` to the end of it and post the entire SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now works this way:

```
Member.includes(:board).where('is_board = ?', true).order('boards.order ASC').references(:board)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick;

```
@display = Member.joins(:board).where(is_board: true).order('boards.order ASC')
```

Also you should use;

```
render 'partial', collection: @display
```

In your view as it's much more efficient and readable.